# Auto minify output Javascript file on elm make

Tags: elm

What's the best way that when you run

```
elm make Main.elm --output elm.js
```

The output Javascript file is already minified?

Comment: sadly not - you have to do it separately as part of your build pipeline. See [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/asset_size.html)

Answer (score 3):

The official guide has an example if you're using UglifyJS https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/asset_size.html. The tldr is to create a script (such as a bash file on Mac or Linux) that looks like

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# compile
elm make src/Main.elm --optimize --output=elm.js

# minify
uglifyjs elm.js --compress 'pure_funcs=[F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7,F8,F9,A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8,A9],pure_getters,keep_fargs=false,unsafe_comps,unsafe' | uglifyjs --mangle --output elm.min.js
```

This is the approach I use in most of my projects that are Elm only or even light on JS. I do however use [Terser](https://terser.org/) instead of UglifyJS as it has better support for modern JS and accepts the same arguments is I can literally just replace `uglifyjs` with `terser` in the above script.

Comment: If you're on Windows or if you just don't want to make a bash script you could instead create a Node script or any other script you want to run these 2 commands in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The `elm make` command cannot do this for you. However, you can simply run a minifier on the output.

Check out the optimization hint for examples:
https://github.com/elm/compiler/blob/master/hints/optimize.md

Also don't forget to add `--optimize` to `elm make` when building for production.

Comment: +1 Good answer. To improve it a little, maybe you should add the relevant part i.e. the uglify script from the link to your answer. This way the answer itself contains all the needed information and the link provides extra details for those who are interested.